# Where can I find vintage hardware to mount a Raleigh 3 bolt chainring?

Tags: chainring, vintage, bolt, raleigh

I need hardware (3 short bolts) for my Raleigh Super Course 10 speed made in Nottingham England in 1973.

The bolts hold the front large chainring to the smaller chainring that the pedals are mounted to.   Can these bolts be purchased?

Comment: Hardware store or bike shop, though the shape of the head may be critical for clearance.

Comment: So you need chainring bolts to secure your chainrings to the crankarm/spider ?

Comment: It's unlikely that many people in this community are familiar components used on `70s British Raleighs. If you add some photos of the cranks and chainrings it will give us a better chance of providing a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the "three bolts"  you have something similar to this image, which appears to use three simple bolts, although I can't find what the threading is.

> TL;DR, there's an updated answer below all this waffle.

Sheldon's relevant page is at https://www.sheldonbrown.com/raleigh26.html and specifically fingers the Nottingham factory for making up their own standards, and did this right through to the 1990s.

[image]

If you have access to one of the bolts, then its possible to identify it using some basic machining tools.

1. A Thread pitch gauge will tell you how many turns per inch (TPI) (aka the "pitch")
2. A micrometer or Vernier caliper will tell you the outer diameter.  It will probably be a straight thread - if the diameter changes along the length, then it could be a tapered thread
3. Eyeball the thread form - is it an even triangle (most likely) or something weird.

More info at https://www.classicfasteners.com.au/content/Identifying_threads.pdf and

A couple of useful thread identication charts are

- http://almetal.nl/en/techinfo/gti/ticas.htm
- https://www.portlandbolt.com/technical/thread-pitch-chart/
- https://www.boltdepot.com/fastener-information/printable-tools/default.aspx

I'd just about guarantee its not a metric thread, but it could be Imperial,  UNF, UNEF, or something older and weirder like Whitworth.  Heck I even have some "BA2" bolts in my British Landrover from 1973, that standard dates from the days of steam boilers!

Still possible that Raleigh were completely alone and used their own standard bolts too - which may need to be made specially.  You could potentially retap the holes to a normal metric standard bolt too.

Finally if you don't have the bolt, all this is possible to measure using the threaded hole in the crank too.  Just a lot more fiddly.

---

If you do buy commercial bolts, try for stainless steel or high tensile (or both if you can) and use antisieze.  Try and avoid using the cheapest low-carbon chinese cheese bolts from the local discount store.

---

### UPDATE

> I believe the 3 chainring bolts are 9/32" Outer Diameter and the thread is a 26 tpi whitworth thread.

<sup>From https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/703071-chainring-bolts-cottered-3-arm-crankset.html</sup>

There is also some discussion that a metric M7x1.0 thread will "fit"

The observant will object and point out that

- Metric flanks have an angle of 60 degrees whereas Whitworth is 55 degrees,
- Metric pitch of 1.0 translates to 25.4 tpi while Raleigh's propriety threading is 26 tpi
- and 9/32"= 0.28125 " = 7.14375 mm which is pretty close to a 7mm bolt.

Add some thread locker to help stop it walking out, or you might have room for a jam-nut on the other side, maybe.

Comment: Thanks for you help !!I've just sent an email to the Raleigh company in Nottingham England  ro inquire on availability If any. I am awaiting on their response I'll keep you posted on my progress jw